# Rcpp C/C++ using structs and char*

Tags: c++, struct, char, constants, rcpp

Newbie to C/C++ and Rcpp.

I'm currently trying to modify examples I find (in this case I modified the "yada" module example http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-modules.pdf) and extend them to test my understanding.

The example I have currently compiles but, does not have the expected behaviour. My guess it that I'm missing something, but I can't determine what is missing from I find in the docs.  Any help would be much appreciated.

the example code is below.

```
library(inline)
fx=cxxfunction(,plugin="Rcpp",include='#include<Rcpp.h>
#include<string>

typedef struct containerForChars {const char *b;} containChar;

containChar cC;

const char* toConstChar(std::string s){return s.c_str();}

void setB(std::string s){
    cC.b = toConstChar(s);
}

std::string getB(void){
    std::string cs = cC.b;
    return cs;
}
RCPP_MODULE(ex1){
  using namespace Rcpp;
  function("setB",&getB);
  function("getB",&getB);
}')
mod=Module("ex1",getDynLib(fx))
f<-mod$setB
g<-mod$getB
f("asdf")
g()
```

Instead of `f("asdf")` setting `cC.b` to `"asdf"`, I get the following error,

```
Error in f("asdf") : unused argument ("asdf")
```

My hope is that the arg to `f()` will be set as the value for `cC.b`, and `g()` will retrieve or get the value I set with `f`.  My guess is that whatever magic that Module and RCPP_MODULE do isn't capable of using the struct I defined. I guess hoping for it to work wasn't enough :P.

Comment: "but, does not have the expected behaviour." to be able to help you, you'd have to enlighten us as to what behavior you expect?

Comment: Edited the question at the bottom with a little bit of motivation for the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Common typo. Instead of

```
 function("setB",&getB);
 function("getB",&getB);
```

do

```
 function("setB",&setB);     # set, not get
 function("getB",&getB);
```

and then everything works:

```
R> f("asdf")    
R> g()          
[1] "asdf" 
R>
```

I'd also add `library(inline)` at the top.